# Is it possible from the Apple Watch app to know if the host app is in foreground?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I know that from the Watch app we can wake up the host app with `openParentApplication(userInfo:reply)`, but is there a way to know if the host app is currently running before calling `openParentApplication`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can track the `NSExtensionContext` [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSExtensionContext_Class/) but you don't know what state the host app is running when your watch app launches.

You could put a flag in `NSUserDefaults` and have the host app change that flag in the applicationDelegate's `applicationWilllEnterForeground`, `applicationDidEnterBackground` and so forth. Then share the defaults as described in the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1).

If that seems like a weird way to use `NSUserDefaults` you'd need to do something with the Darwin notifications. [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) is built on top of of the Darwin stuff and works great for a lot of people.

Short answer: pick a method of communicating between the host app and the watch that doesn't rely on `openParentApplication` & the reply and then just have the host app relay status information to the watch app.

Answer (score 0):

openParentApplication will not bring your iPhone app into an active state. Therefore, an easy way would be to call openParentApplication. In that method, just return the following bool by putting it in an NSDictionary that is returned with reply():

```
   ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `openParentApplication:reply:` method in your Watch controller to send requests to that app and receive a response.

When you call the `openParentApplication:reply:` method, iOS launches or wakes the containing iOS app in the background and calls the `application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:` method of its app delegate. The app delegate performs the request using the provided dictionary and then returns a reply to the WatchKit extension. You can read more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html).

**In AppDelegate**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply {
    let state = UIApplication.applicationState
    let replyDict = ["appState" : state]
    reply(replyDict)
}
```

**In WatchController**

```
WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(dictionary) {
        (replyDict, error) -> Void in
    //You will get the replyDict here, which contains application state.
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: cool thanks! I got a question, where does the "error" variable comes from in the openParentApplication method? It's not being passed by handleWatchKitExtensionRequest's block, so I wonder how is it just there.

Comment: "error" is an NSError object indicating if a problem occurred or nil if there was no error. I figured when the watchkit cannot open parent application, it receives NSError. There is not much detail I could find.